# The redirect URI included is not valid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I am trying to use GitLab OAuth2 with Spring Boot, but I am continuously getting:

> redirected uri is invalid

I already registered the app in GitLab.

Here is my `application.yml`

```
security:
  oauth2:
   client:
     clientId: CLIENT_ID
     clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET
     userAuthorizationUri: https://gitlab.your-domain.com/oauth/authorize
     accessTokenUri: https://gitlab.your-domain.com/oauth/token
     registered-redirect-uri:
     #- http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gitlab
     - http://localhost:8080
     tokenName: oauth_token
     authenticationScheme: query
     clientAuthenticationScheme: form
   resource:
     userInfoUri: https://gitlab.your-domain.com/api/v4/user
```

and a simple Spring REST class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class DemoApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Finally the `index.html` file:

```html
<body>
<h1>Demo</h1>
<div class="container unauthenticated">
    With GitLab: <a href="/login/gitlab">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="container authenticated" style="display: none">
    Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
    <div>
        <button onClick="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("/user", function(data) {
        $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
        $(".unauthenticated").hide()
        $(".authenticated").show()
    });
    var logout = function() {
        $.post("/logout", function() {
            $("#user").html('');
            $(".unauthenticated").show();
            $(".authenticated").hide();
        })
        return true;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

I am able to login to GitLab, and authorization is also done successfully, finally when it came to redirecting to the base URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080
```

its saying the redirect URL is not valid.

Here is my `POM.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oauth-gitlab-demo-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.1.1</version> -->
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.2.0</version> -->
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You redirect url is http://localhost:8080 in yaml. And you are redirecting to http://localhost:8080/user. Is that what you want?

Comment: /user is the final end point , thats a typo here , i ll edit it .. thanks but still even if i am putting it to localhost:8080/ i am facing the same issue. Is there any other issue you can figure out in code ?

Comment: @dur i am adding the pom.xml also here and yea my redirect url is same as that of gitlab.. but what i have figured out is spring is automatically defining the redirect url as localhost:8080/login  , no matters how many times or whatever i change in redirect_url

Comment: @dur  , it exists under security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=set<String> . i changed it to security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri="redirect-uri" and then i used one more property security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false and now its working as spring boot by default takes the base-url/login as redirect-uri , Still thanks a lot for your support man , as then only i get to know where is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error in Gitlab and I fixed it by changing `http://localhost:5000` to `http://localhost:5000/`!!